# Combine PDF using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pdf, merge, pypdf

Anyone have ideas on how to combine two pdfs into single A4 pdf file. I can combine on landscape, but not on portrait. Below is my code using Python3 and PyPDF2.

**(assuming there are 2 pdf files in "output" directory which named "left.pdf" and "right.pdf")**

```
import sys import os import PyPDF2

from pdfrw import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PageMerge, IndirectPdfDict from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PageObject

    inpfn = 'output.pdf'
    outfn = 'output/right.pdf'
    reader = PdfReader(inpfn)
    writer = PdfWriter(outfn)
    writer.addpage(adjust3(reader.pages[0]))
    writer.trailer.Info = IndirectPdfDict(reader.Info or {})
    writer.write()

    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    path_to_files = r'output/'
    for root, dirs, file_names in os.walk(path_to_files):
        for file_name in file_names:
            merger.append(path_to_files + file_name)
    merger.write("file_gabungan.pdf")
    merger.close()
```

Comment: And so what does your current script do that isn't right?

Comment: the script work with 2 genereted pages on single pdf,
what i want is merge 2 pdf files into single page pdf